# Change autoindent offset in C after inserting a curly bracket

Tags: emacs

I am relatively new to emacs environment and I have trouble find the solution for this problem.

what happens is when I insert a curly bracket `e.g. foo(`, it automatically adds 4 spaces in the front of the current line.

I am currently using bsd C style. Is there any setting that I can change this behavior? I have tried changing the C Basic Offset but it has no effect so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emacs isn't really adding spaces, instead it's "fixing" the indentation, which it most likely thinks is 4 spaces per indentation level. `c-basic-offset` is the variable you want to change, you should put this in your `.emacs`:

```
(setq-default c-basic-offset 2)
```

You need `setq-default`. If you just use `setq`, it will only change it for the current buffer.